# Loop a shortened video html tag

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I have a react app and am using a video html tag with a video url.  I need to only play a portion of the video from the url, so adding #t=6,12

But that seems to disable the loop. Does anyone know how to make the loop work whilst only playing a portion of the video?

Thanks in advance.

```
<video
  src={`${option.videoUrl}#t=6,12`}
  autoPlay
  controls={false}
  loop
  muted
  playsInline
/>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the version `React@14.` it support video element, you can do lots of actions with `video element` and write your logic accordingly.

Can you please read through this [link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html#notable-enhancements)

Or, here in summary,

> React DOM now supports these media events on audio and video tags: onAbort, onCanPlay, onCanPlayThrough, onDurationChange, onEmptied, onEncrypted, onEnded, onError, onLoadedData, onLoadedMetadata, onLoadStart, onPause, onPlay, onPlaying, onProgress, onRateChange, onSeeked, onSeeking, onStalled, onSuspend, onTimeUpdate, onVolumeChange, onWaiting.

Sample code:

```js
<video
  src={url}
  autoPlay
  controls={true}
  loop
  playsInline
  onPlay={() => console.log("play start")}
  onPause={() => console.log("pause")}
  onTimeUpdate={() => console.log("time update")}
/>
```

Comment: Yep, but loop doesn't work if playing only part of video e.g. <video src={${option.videoUrl}#t=6,12} loop> that's my issue

Comment: you can control by managing state and restarting video, by using available methods like `onTimeUpdate` `onPlay` and more.